# Would it be wrong if you don't add the article "A" and still use the auxiliary "IS" with the word "SHEEP"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, articles, uncountable-nouns, countability

I researched the word sheep, and its special singular and plural features. I understand plural and singular is the same and it can take **"is"** or **"are"** and the word will not change. I read many sentences and they all focus on plural form won't change. However, they don't focus on the combination **"Sheep+no article+IS......"**

Here is what I have concluded:

- A sheep is grazing.(correct)
- The sheep is grazing (correct)
- The sheep are grazing. (correct)
- Sheep are grazing. (correct)
- **Sheep is grazing. (!!!!!!!!)**

As you see, I tried to list some alternatives and but the last one really confuses me.

When it comes to usage of **sheep without the article** **"A"**, it seems that it always means plural. In other words, **"Sheep is grazing"** wouldn't not be possible without the article **"A"**. In other words, "**Sheep"** can not be followed by the auxiliary **"IS"** unless it starts with **"A SHEEP......"**.. This is what I conclude.

I researched but I could not find any explanation whether I can say **"Sheep is grazing"** (without the article **"a"** to refer to a sheep. I came to conclusion that **"Sheep is grazing"** would be wrong.

Still, as a non-native speaker, I can't be sure. Would it be wrong if I say **"Sheep is grazing."** (without the article **"a"**) to refer to a sheep?

Comment: ***A car** is moving, **The car** is moving, **The cars** are moving, **Cars** are moving.* But you can't use the singular with no article, so ***Car** is moving* and ***Sheep** is moving* are both invalid.

Comment: "sheep is grazing" is not grammatical, as you have ascertained, And this applies to all animal nouns that don't take an s in the plural: moose, elk, deer, salmon, trout. For example. There are others.  And fish, in terms of catching them.

Comment: I asked this because many grammer sites say "sheep" can be plural or singular, and you can't understand from the look of the work and that you can only understand from the context if a sentence is about a sheep or many sheep. However, I saw that no, it is always plural without the article "A", there is nothing special about it.

Comment: yunus: Not *quite* - if I say *"I'll sell you my sheep"*, only *context* tells you whether I'm offering a single sheep or a whole flock. I *might* have said *"I'll sell you **a** sheep"* in the former case, but no-one would normally say *"I'll sell you sheep"* with no "determiner" at all in the second case.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Ah yes, that is what I missed apparently. This is where the context come into play. I learned a new thing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

"Sheep is grazing" is incorrect, for the reasons you have stated.  *Is* is a singular verb conjugation, so you must be referring to a singular sheep.  But referring to a singular count noun with no determiner is an error.